# Removing numerical artifacts from a table of values

Tags: list-manipulation, numerics

For some function, `f[x, y]`, I have generated a table of values

```
Table[f[x, y], {x, {1, 2, 3}}, {y, {1, 2, 3}}]
```

which generates

> ```
> {{f[1, 1], f[1, 2], f[1, 3]}, 
>  {f[2, 1], f[2, 2], f[2, 3]}, 
>  {f[3, 1], f[3, 2], f[3, 3]}}.
> ```

However, many of these values are negative or complex; however, these are numerical artifacts, and I want to set them to 0, unless they are positive real.

If I have a large table of this kind, is there a way to set values that are negative or complex to 0?

Answer (score 3):

Here is one approach:

```
t = {{-3, 5, 2 + 7 I}, {1/2, -0.7, 1.3 - I}};

t*Boole@Positive@t // Chop
```

> ```
> {{0, 5, 0}, {1/2, 0, 0}}
> ```

Answer (score 2):

`ReplaceAll` (`/.`) is a very handy way of easily replacing elements of a list:

```
t = {{-3, 5, 2 + 7 I}, {1/2, -0.7, 1.3 - I}};
t /. {x_ /; ! Positive[x] -> 0}

(* {{0, 5, 0}, {1/2, 0, 0}} *)
```

If you ever want to just get rid of all the complex or negative elements (instead of setting them to zero) you can do

```
t /. {x_ /; ! Positive[x] -> Nothing}
Cases[t, x_ /; Positive[x], 2]

(* {{5}, {1/2}}
   {5, 1/2}     *)
```

(there are also many, many other ways of doing that).

Answer (score 2):

If the artifacts are sufficiently small, you can use just [`Chop`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Chop.html).

To demonstrate this, I first need data that exhibits the right characteristics.

```
positive[] := RandomReal[{1., 5.}]
negative[] := -RandomReal[{1., 5.} 10^-11]
complex[] := positive[] + I RandomChoice[{-1, 1}] negative[]

SeedRandom[2];
data = Through[RandomChoice[{positive, negative, complex}, 12][]]
```

> ```
> {4.98146 + 2.89887*10^-11 I, 
>  2.54797 + 2.45814*10^-11 I, 
>  3.62342, 
>  2.97821 + 1.91297*10^-11 I, 
>  -2.31221*10^-11, 
>  4.50281, 
>  2.01652 - 1.78838*10^-11 I, 
>  -2.30211*10^-11, 
>  -4.07092*10^-11, 
>  2.6675*10^-11, 
>  4.15392, 
>  -1.68444*10^-11}
> ```

With this data

```
Chop[data]
```

gives

> ```
> {4.98146, 2.54797, 3.62342, 2.97821, 0, 4.50281, 2.01652, 0, 0, 0, 4.15392, 0}
> ```

Note that `Chop` takes a 2nd argument that allow you to adjust the granularity at which it operates.